# Getting a CASE syntax error in my query using sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query and it appears to look okay to me however when I run this query in SQLPro I get the following error message (I presume it maybe an error specific to sqlite?:

error:

```
near "CASE": syntax error (Line 14)
```

query

```
SELECT team, SUM(Win) As Won, SUM(Loss) as Lost, SUM(score) as Score
FROM
  ( SELECT home_team_id as team, 
    CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Win, 
    CASE WHEN home_score < away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Loss, home_score as score
FROM community_results
  UNION ALL
  SELECT away_team_id as team
    CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Win, 
    CASE WHEN away_score < home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Loss, away_score as score
FROM community_results
) t
GROUP BY team
ORDER By Won, Lost DESC, Score
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after:

```
SELECT away_team_id as team
```

Comment: doh?! and this is why I should get some rest... thank you

Comment: We all overlook the simple things, thinking we couldn't have possibly done something like that  :)

Answer (score -1):

How about this;)

```
SELECT team, SUM(Win) As Won, SUM(Loss) as Lost, SUM(score) as Score
FROM
  ( SELECT home_team_id as team, 
    CASE WHEN home_score > away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Win, 
    CASE WHEN home_score < away_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Loss, home_score as score
FROM community_results
  UNION ALL
  SELECT away_team_id as team,
    CASE WHEN away_score > home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Win, 
    CASE WHEN away_score < home_score THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Loss, away_score as score
FROM community_results
) t
GROUP BY team
ORDER By Won, Lost DESC, Score
```